# Can I use a part of the background image as a separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think the header covers it all. Can a small let's say 40x40 part of the 1600x1200 background image of an HTML (javascript, jquery) page be used as another div. I mean I take a 40x40 part of the image and set it as a div with id "div1" and so on for another parts. The idea is, that the divs are set to the background image, so that if watched from a smaller screen with the "fit in" function there will be no misplacement. I hope you get the idea.

Best Regards.

Comment: My friend, this is the internet.  Here, you can do and be anything.  Enjoy your stay.

Comment: Should I wait of a possible implementation :D. But thanks anyway :D

Comment: try providing a jsfiddle. Explain in detail.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/64FhB/
 I don't know what else to write in jsfiddle, cause everything else is irrelevant to the problem. If I use some invisible gifs with 40x40 pixels and set them to coordinates, they will be on the same coordinates if I open the browser on half the screen, but the part of the picture they're supposed to represent will be different, cause the picture will be fitted into the screen and therefore smaller.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/64FhB/1/ using placeholder images is nice for demoing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64FhB/2/)

**CSS**

```
html {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat center center fixed;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    background-position: 0px -30px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

---

### Note

This uses the sprite technique and should work fine for this scenario.

---

### References:

- http://www.guistuff.com/css/css_imagetech1.html

  ---

### [Demo pulled from Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/yBjt4/)

**CSS**

```
.icons {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(http://www.guistuff.com/css/images/sixicons.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.icon_1 {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.icon_2 {
    background-position: -40px 0px;
}
.icon_3 {
    background-position: -80px 0px;
}
.icon_4 {
    background-position: 0px -40px;
}
.icon_5 {
    background-position: -40px -40px;
}
.icon_6 {
    background-position: -80px -40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="icons icon_1" style="float:left;"></span>
&nbsp; - Icon No.1<br/>

<span class="icons icon_2" style="float:left;"></span>
&nbsp; - Icon No.2<br/>

<span class="icons icon_3" style="float:left;"></span>
&nbsp; - Icon No.3<br/>

<span class="icons icon_4" style="float:left;"></span>
&nbsp; - Icon No.4<br/>

<span class="icons icon_5" style="float:left;"></span>
&nbsp; - Icon No.5<br/>

<span class="icons icon_6" style="float:left;"></span>
&nbsp; - Icon No.6<br/>
```

Comment: what would the name of the new div be. If for example I want to name a certain part of the image as div1, and refer to it later in the javascript code?

Comment: @user3095198 added a demo of sprites it is directly pulled from the reference i provided.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use an image as a CSS Image Sprite.  You can set a background image on a DIV and then adjust the background-position as needed.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HarmonicApps/75GjA/)

```
    .big-image {
        background-image:url(http://img2.netcarshow.com/McLaren-F1_1993_1024x768_wallpaper_01.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        display:block;
    }
    .img-sec-1 {
        background-position: -175px -268px;
        height:40px !IMPORTANT;
        width:40px !IMPORTANT;
    }
    .img-sec-2 {
        background-position: -270px -290px;
        height:50px !IMPORTANT;
        width:50px !IMPORTANT;
    }
```